# Using react redux and redux persist

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

I want to perform some calculations and dispatch an action whenever a user opens my app. This is the relevant part of my code (App.js):

```
class ConnectedMainNavigator extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    updatedCustomers = this.props.customers.map(customer => {
      let frequency = 0
      currentDate = new Date()
      customer.transactions.forEach(transaction => {
        if (daysFromTransaction(transaction.date, currentDate) < 30)
          frequency++;
      })
      return {
        ...customer,
        frequency: frequency
      }
    })
    this.props.updateFrequency([...updatedCustomers])
  }
  render() {
    return <MainNavigator/>
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  customers: state.customers
})

connect(mapStateToProps,{updateFrequency: updateFrequency})(ConnectedMainNavigator)


export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isReady: false,
  }

  async componentWillMount() {
      await Expo.Font.loadAsync({
         'MaterialIcons': require('@expo/vector-icons/fonts/MaterialIcons.ttf')
      });
      this.setState({isReady: true})
    }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isReady)
      return <Expo.AppLoading/>

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
          <ConnectedMainNavigator/>
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

I have created a separated component (ConnectedMainNavigator) that is connect to my store. I am rendering this component within my App component. However, I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
>
> This error is located at:
>       in ConnectedMainNavigator (at App.js:82)
>       ...

Can somebody tell me why am getting this error? Also is there a better way to perform calculations whenever your app is opened?

Comment: it looks as if your customers prop is not an array. What does your default state look like?

Comment: Please share the state in reducer

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because `this.props.customers` is null.

You didn't share your reducer, so we can't see the initial state of `customers`.